# mysql before insert trigger

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.1

I try to create following trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE trigger insert_processor
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

set new.val = trim(new.val);
set new.val2 = upper(new.val);

END$$
```

and it fails with following error message

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 8
```

What could be a reason?

MySql server version: `5.1.40-community`

Client: `phpMyAdmin 3.3.8`

Comment: There are no syntax errors. What MySQL client do you use?

Comment: @Devart, updated question with version server/client information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look if there is a DILIMITER field in your phpmyadmin version, just below the SQL editor. Set your delimiter there, for example - '$$', and write this SQL code -

```
CREATE trigger insert_processor
BEFORE INSERT ON tbl
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

set new.val = trim(new.val);
set new.val2 = upper(new.val);

END$$
```